# Blurred panel over a video player

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-videoview, blurry

I have a special design requiring for the app I'm developing right now.

Right now, I have a third-party private video library which plays a video stream. The design of this screen includes a translucent panel overlaid on top of the video, blurring the portion of the video that lies behind.

Normally in order to blur the background, you are supposed to take a screenshot of the view behind, blur it and use it as an image for the foreground view.

In this case, the video keeps on playing, so the blurred image changes every frame. How would you implement this then?

A possible solution would be to create a thread, taking screenshots, cropping them and put them as a background. Even better if that view is a SurfaceView, I guess. But I'm wondering what would be the best approach in this case. Would a thread that is continually taking screenshots create a huge performance impact? Is it possible to feed a surfaceView buffer with these images?

Thanks!

Comment: i guess you go with 2nd option.. surfaceView buffer

Answer (score 1):

A SurfaceView surface is a consumer of graphics buffers.  You can't have two producers for one consumer, which means you can't send the video to it and draw on it at the same time.

You can have multiple layers; the SurfaceView surface is on a separate layer behind the View UI layer.  So you could play the video to the SurfaceView's surface, and draw your blur rectangle on the SurfaceView's view.  (Normally the SurfaceView's view is completely transparent, and is just used as a place-holder for layout purposes.)

Another option would be to render the video frame to a [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html).  You would then render that texture to the SurfaceView surface with GLES, and render the blur rectangle on top.  You can find an example of treating live camera input as a GLES texture in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) ("texture from camera" activity).  This has the additional advantage that, since you're not interacting with the View system -- the SurfaceView surface is composited by the system, not the app -- you can do it all on an independent thread.

In any event, rendering, grabbing a screenshot, and re-rendering is going to be slower than the options described above.

For more details about why things work the way they do, see the [Android System-Level Graphics](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html) architecture doc.